# How to use count in sql based on a IF condition

Tags: mysql, sql

From this table

| groupId | flag | flagValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 500 |
| 2 | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 3 | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 3 | 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |

I need this result

| groupId | flag1 | flag0 | valFlag1 | valFlag0 | totalFlags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 210 | 500 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 100 | 100 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1000 | 100 | 2 |

where

- flag1 is number of times flag is 1 for a particular group
- flag0 is number of times flag is 0 for a particular group
- valFlag1 is sum of flagVal when flag is 1
- valFlag0 is sum of flagVal when flag is 0
- totalFlags is sum of total flags associated with a group

I am stuck as to how to actually count values based on an IF condition.
Anyhelp is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a table named `group_table` with your values
Try using this:

```
SELECT 
 g.`groupId`,
 SUM(g.`flag`=1 ) AS flag1,
 SUM(g.`flag`=0) AS flag0,
 SUM(CASE WHEN g.`flag`=1 THEN g.`flagValue` ELSE 0 END) AS valFalg1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN g.`flag`=0 THEN g.`flagValue` ELSE 0 END) AS valFalg0,
 COUNT(*) AS totalFlags
FROM
  `group_table` g 
GROUP BY g.`groupId`
```

If you have to use the `IF`,

```
SELECT
 g.`groupId`,
 IF(g.`flag`=1,1,0 ) AS flag1,
 IF(g.`flag`=0,1,0) AS flag0,
 SUM(IF(g.`flag`=1,g.`flagValue`,0 )) AS valFalg1,
 SUM(IF(g.`flag`=0,g.`flagValue`,0 )) AS valFalg0,
 COUNT(*) AS totalFlags
FROM
  `group_table` g 
GROUP BY g.`groupId`, flag1, flag0
```

They'll produce the same result

Comment: This absolutely worked. Thanks a lot, kind sir!

Comment: *They'll produce the same result*- No, they would not. You should use the `SUM` (or the `COUNT`  with `NULL`s in the `IF` statement) aggregation for the `flag1` and `flag0` columns in your second query, otherwise you should include them in the `GROUP BY` clause, and then the result would be completely different. At this point your second query, that is the OP's case, can not be executed

Comment: What is the table alias `g` used for ?

Comment: @Alexey, where is the null? Can you provide a quick demo in some SQL fiddle and show what you are trying to say. I cannot quite catch you.

Comment: @Asgar, here it is https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e276ca9dc22b89a3ea798b2ffe5c3c8. Correct your answer and i reset my downvote

Comment: Oh, okay! I see that.  `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. I have had it changed for months now. Thank you for bringing that to notice. I overlooked it.